# Evaluating the integral $\int_0^1 \frac{\cos bx}{\sqrt{x^2+s^2} }dx$

Tags: definite-integrals, approximation, closed-form

I'd really love to evaluate this integral exactly in terms of known functions, because for large $b$ it becomes a pain numerically.

$$I(b,s)=\int_0^1 \frac{\cos bx}{\sqrt{x^2+s^2} }dx$$

Didn't get anywhere wth integration by parts, or series. I want an expression valid for both large and small values of the parameters.

Note: we have $b= \pi n$, where $n$ is an integer.

For $s \gg 1$ we can expand the root as a series and get a good approximation. However, this case is of small use to me, as in general $s$ is of the order of $1$ or smaller.

So here's my latest attempt:

**Edited**

$$x=s \sinh v$$

$$I(b,s)=\int_0^{\sinh^{-1} \frac{1}{s}} \cos \left(bs \sinh v \right) dv$$

Let's try integration by parts:

$$U=\cos \left(bs \sinh v \right) \\ dV=dv$$

$$dU=-bs\sin \left(bs \sinh v \right) \cosh v \\ V=v$$

$$I(b,s)=\cos b \sinh^{-1} \frac{1}{s}+bs \int_0^{\sinh^{-1} \frac{1}{s}} v \sin \left(bs \sinh v \right) \cosh v dv$$

$$I(b,s)=\cos b \sinh^{-1} \frac{1}{s}+bs \int_0^{\frac{1}{s}} \sinh^{-1} r \sin \left(bs r \right) dr$$

$$I(b,s)=\cos b \sinh^{-1} \frac{1}{s}+b \int_0^1 \sinh^{-1} \frac{x}{s} \sin \left(b x \right) dx$$

This seems a little better, at least we separated the special case $I(0,s)$, which is the first term. Not sure how to continue.

Using the fact that $b= \pi n$, we can transform the integral as:

$$b \int_0^1 \sinh^{-1} \frac{x}{s} \sin \left(b x \right) dx=\pi \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (-1)^k \int_0^1 \sinh^{-1} \left( \frac{t+k}{ns} \right) \sin \pi t dt$$

The function $\sinh^{-1}$ is pretty nice, it has a logarithmic growth, and doesn't blow up anywhere. I guess, this could be the way to get a good approximation, especially since we have an alternating sum.

Comment: Have you tried by using Contour Integration, Residue theorem etc. on the function $\displaystyle \frac{e^{ibz}}{\sqrt{z^2+s^2}}$ around the contour $|z|=1$

Comment: @SujitBhattacharyya, I'm bad at contour integration, especially with roots, aren't there branch cuts to deal with? If you could show me how to do that...

Comment: If you just need an approximation why don't you use the trapezoidal rule or some other such method?
WolframAlpha didn't seem to find any expansion in terms of standard mathematical functions.

Comment: @SorinTirc, approximation is the last option I'd consider, and trapezoidal rule is horrible for large $b$ (the function oscillates like crazy). I've used numerical methods on this, and they are slow and inaccurate, even with the best Mathematica has to offer. Moreover, see my edit. I think I'm on the right path with the exact evaluation...

Comment: In Mathematica `11.3` we can use command: `AsymptoticIntegrate[Cos[b x]/Sqrt[
 x^2 + s^2], {x, 0, 1}, {b, Infinity, 2}, Assumptions -> s > 0]` and we get:$\frac{\sin (b)}{b \sqrt{s^2+1}}-\frac{\cos (b)}{b^2 \left(s^2+1\right)^{3/2}}$ for `b->Infinity`

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk, thank you! I didn't know about this new command, very useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting a grasp of the original problem: we want to find the asymptotic behaviour of the Fourier coefficients of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+s^2}}\in L^2(0,1)$. Since the inverse Laplace transform of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+s^2}}$ is $J_0(as)$ and the Laplace transform of $\cos(\pi n x)\mathbb{1}_{(0,1)}(x)$ is $\frac{a}{a^2+n^2\pi^2}-\frac{a(-1)^n}{e^a(a^2+\pi^2 n^2)}$, we have

$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\cos(\pi n x)}{\sqrt{x^2+s^2}}\,dx = \underbrace{\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{a J_0(as)}{a^2+\pi^2 n^2}\,da}_{K_0(\pi n s)} + (-1)^{n+1}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{a J_0(as)}{e^a(a^2+\pi^2 n^2)}\,da $$
which is fairly easy to approximate numerically due to the known bounds for Bessel functions.
Close to the origin $J_0(a)$ can be approximated through its rapidly-convergent Maclaurin series, far from the origin we have Tricomi's $J_0(a)\approx\frac{\sin(a)+\cos(a)}{\sqrt{\pi a}}$. For $K_0$ we have [Hankel's expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function).

In particular the Fourier coefficients of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+s^2}}$ decay like $\frac{1}{n^2 s^3}$.

It is also interesting to point out a curious inequality provided by Cauchy-Schwarz:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}\left|\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{a J_0(as)}{e^a(a^2+\pi^2 n^2)}\,da\right|^2&\leq& \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{J_0(as)^2}{e^{2a}}\,da\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{a^2}{(a^2+\pi^2 n^2)^2}\,da\\&=&\frac{1}{8n\,\text{AGM}(1,\sqrt{1+s^2})}\leq\frac{1}{8n}(1+s^2)^{-1/4}.\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: Thank you very much! This should speed up the algorithm, once I get a handle on which approximation works where. Also should help with the other similar integrals, as they are just a part of the larger problem

Comment: I don't think the $1/(e^{\pi n s} \sqrt {2 n s})$ part is true, there are powers of $n$ that don't cancel out. I've added an answer.

Comment: @Maxim: you're right, now fixing.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio, your integral expression turned out to be very helpful, as a follow up, maybe you have any advice [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3000535/269624)?

Comment: The second integral is great for Gauss-Laguerre quadrature, it's fast and accurate for a few points. This works for me much better than any other ways I tried, so thank you again

Comment: Wanted to thank you a third time, since I still use this answer in my calculations. Very useful for averaging Coulomb potential over a quantum well

Answer (score 3):

The asymptotic for large $n$ is determined by the behaviour of the integrand at $x = \pm 1$. Choosing a contour going in the direction $i$ from $x = -1$ and then in the direction $-i$ towards $x = 1$ and expanding the non-exponential part, we have
$$\frac 1 {\sqrt {x^2 + s^2}} \bigg\rvert_{x = -1 + i \xi} =
\frac 1 {\sqrt {1 + s^2}} + \frac {i \xi} {(1 + s^2)^{3/2}} + O(\xi^2), \\
\frac 1 {\sqrt {x^2 + s^2}} \bigg\rvert_{x = 1 + i \xi} =
\frac 1 {\sqrt {1 + s^2}} - \frac {i \xi} {(1 + s^2)^{3/2}} + O(\xi^2).$$
The contributions from the first terms will cancel out, leaving
$$I(\pi n, s) =
\frac 1 2\int_{-1}^1 \frac {e^{i \pi n x}} {\sqrt {x^2 + s^2}} dx \sim
i \int_0^\infty
 \frac {i \xi} {(1 + s^2)^{3/2}} e^{-i \pi n - \pi n \xi} d\xi = \\
\frac {(-1)^{n - 1}} {\pi^2 (1 + s^2)^{3/2} n^2},
\quad n \to \infty, \,n \in \mathbb N.$$

Comment: Thank you, Maxim, this was also very helpful

Answer (score 0):

**Just a comment**

The integral is the real part of
$$\int^1_0\frac{e^{ibx}}{\sqrt{s^2+x^2}}dx$$

If we make a substitution $x=is\cos t$, without dealing with branch cuts rigorously we can obtain

$$-i\int^{\cos^{-1}(-i/s)}_{\pi/2}e^{-bs\cos t}dt$$

Essentially,
$$I(b,s)=\Im~ \int^{\cos^{-1}(-i/s)}_{\pi/2}e^{-bs\cos t}dt $$
or
$$I(b,s)=-\Im~ \int^{\sin^{-1}(-i/s)}_{0}e^{-bs\sin t}dt $$

which suggests a relation with Bessel functions. However, due to the upper and lower limits not being $\pm\pi$, the normal Bessel functions cannot be used. I think there might be a need to define some kind of ‘incomplete Bessel function’ to write the integral in closed form.